# Is it a good practice to implement admin pages in a mobile application?

Tags: web-application, mobile, authorization, administration

So let's say there's a page on the website that shows the admin all the messages that came in from the users since he last logged in.

And it's implemented on the mobile application, with checks in the app to stop this view from showing to normal users AND checks on the server based on the user's role (token-based system) to send back the admin data or not.

I had a convo with a colleague earlier about this and he insisted that implementing any admin features on a mobile app is bad practice, Is it?

Comment: What makes mobile special that there would be a different consideration?

Comment: @schroeder I don't think there is a difference, but I was asking in fear that I'm missing something.

Comment: The difference here is that you are putting checks in the app, which can be discovered and bypassed. But you mitigated that problem.

Comment: Is your colleague's concerns about security or UX? e.g. it's more difficult to perform admin functionality/display detailed admin settings on a phone than on a large desktop monitor with a mouse? If you're merely showing messages, that may be something very convenient for an admin to be able to check on their phone from anywhere instead of requiring them to get to a laptop. If the messages contain sensitive information and you're concerned that could leak if the admin's device is lost/stolen then you can look into MDM to help manage that.